# When is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ an Euclidean domain?

Tags: ring-theory

Where $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not a perfect square.

This problem appeared in our exam and now I'm asking how was I supposed to answer?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, please I would suggest you to explain what you tried to do to solve the problem, so others could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It is rather complex if it was formulated that way, but I don't know the context.

I'll try to explain what is known.

First note general results exist for the *ring of integers* of $\,\mathbf Q(\sqrt d)$, which happens to be $\,\mathbf Z(\sqrt d)$ if and only id $d\not\equiv 1\mod 4$.
Second,there is only a finite list of such rings that are euclidean for the algebraic norm:
$$d={} –11, –7, –3, –2, –1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 29, 33, 37, 41, 57, 73.$$

For $d=69$ and $d=14$, the rings of integers are euclidian for *another norm*. A conjecture by Gauss states that, for $d>0$, there an infinity of  such rings that are principal, and that among them, two at most are not euclidean. If Riemann's hypothesis is true, they're all euclidean. This conjecture is unproved as yet.

If $d<0$, the ring of integers is principal if and only $d$ is one of the five values already mentioned, plus the values: $-19, -43, -67$  and $-163$.